# Windows Server 2019 + Apache 2.4 + GeoServer 2.15.1 (HTTPS)

Tags: geoserver, windows, jetty, ssl

I have a server with Apache 2.4 on Windows server 2019. I´ve configured Apache to run as HTTPS with corresponding certificate.

I've installed GeoServer 2.15.1 for Windows that use Jetty how server.

I have an error of type

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://localhost/geoserver/UNO/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=secciones_mayor64&WIDTH=981&HEIGHT=799&CRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=-919776.1230229893,5385864.567878975,-901029.941836075,5401132.864278918&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=secciones_mayor64&FEATURE_COUNT=25&I=459&J=496'
>
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I know that problem is because GeoServer runs on HTTP. How can I configure GeoServer or Jetty to use HTTPS?

Comment: This is I think an issue with your Java Servlet engine, not GeoServer

Comment: Hi,I´m not sure because Geoserver use jetty servlet

Comment: It's in the Jetty documentation how to set upp Jetty for https. But I wouldn't go down that road, I would proxy the traffic to GeoServer through apache server and let apache handle all https stuff and act as a reverse proxy in front of Jetty.